# From stored procedure to table

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure: `sp_data` with this structure:

```
BEGIN
SELECT 
.
.
.
order by ... ; 
END
```

This stored procedure works fine.

I am currently exporting the results of the stored procedure to a `.csv` file and then importing the table into MySQL.

What I'm looking for: Stop exporting and importing data. I need to add something to the stored procedure that creates a table and if it exists, it uses `DROP` to make it run again and keep it always updated.

I tried to create an empty table `data` with the same data types as the columns to use:

```
INSERT INTO data (column1, column2,...)
SELECT (same structure as sp_data)
```

the `SELECT` part is fine, but when executing it with `INSERT INTO` there is an error:

`Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''`

And I can't modify the `SELECT` of `sp_data` because someone else did it and other people use it in the company. That's why I'm looking to add what I put above.

Comment: You can check what format your `SELECT (same structure as sp_data)` returns. Just run it separately and have a look

Comment: that part works fine

Comment: Can you make sure that you cast your column as `DOUBLE` (the one that supposed to be double)

Comment: If you really can't change the `SELECT`, you could try disabling strict mode before doing the `INSERT`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: Or try using `INSERT IGNORE`. This should turn the error into a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`IGNORE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#ignore-effect-on-execution) option to downgrade the error to a warning.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO data (column1, column2,...)
SELECT (same structure as sp_data)
```

Comment: OMG it worked perfect. I spent hours looking for the solution, thanks!